# Create virtual environment with specific version of python

Tags: python, pyvenv

I have two versions of python installed

```
C:\>python --version
Python 3.6.4

C:\>python39 --version
Python 3.9.0
```

I can create a virtual environment with the first version

```
C:\temp_folder>python -m venv env1
```

but I can't with the 3.9 version:

```
C:\temp_folder_2>python39 -m venv env2
Error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The env2 folder is created but most of the Scripts files are missing

Answer (score 0):

It should be `python3.9 -m venv env2`

Comment: See the part where OP said `python39 --version` outputs the correct version. So in their system, Python 3.9 is available as `python39`. Some installations alias things, it's not always required to be `python3.9`.